# RabbitMQ Java Consumer app best practice for Ubuntu linux deployment

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm studing how RabbitMQ works with Java, it is almost clear how Producer works and how to implement the Consumer, but I'm still not sure how to deploy the Consumer application to server with a correct threading handling.

Let's say I have a web-application that has to sent some transaction email as producer, this application will push in the queue the messages and it is managed by a container, like Tomcat, that increase/descrease threads to serve multiple requests.

**What is the best practice to deployt the consumer application?**

I have read many tutorials and the RabbitMQ commands are well explained, usually this is the code (from official RabbitMq Hello World):

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.DeliverCallback;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Recv {

    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

        DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
            String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
        };
        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { });
    }
}
```

However it is not clear to me how I should run this application in my server (sure I can start it by command line!) and how am I sure the process will not crash for some reason?

Should I put the channel opening commands in a loop inside a try/catch to be sure it will not exit?

Am I'm in charge of handling thread pool opening/increasing?
Does exists something for this purpose?

Comment: Normally these things are run inside a container (such as Tomcat) and over HTTP.  I haven't actually set up RabbitMQ but you might look at the docs with that idea in mind.

Comment: I would use Tomcat as producer because the application receives inputs from HTTP requests, but I cannot imagine how to run a consumer in Tomcat to send email from the queue. It is not a web application.

Comment: I could imagine Tomcat sending an email, for example on password reset request, and I could imagine Tomcat receiving an email too, for example when a web app is the front end of an email list server.  The [RabbitMQ devtool page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html) mentions clients for Spring, which is almost entirely a Java web app framework afaik.  Your application may be different, so you might want to clarify what it is you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I know Spring quite well, but I cannot undersrand how to run a the consumer process in a safe way. May I can open a single thread process? Unfortunately the docs about Consumer implementation is missing this part.

Comment: I think your real question is how to deploy a RabbitMQ consumer inside of a JEE web application.  Saying "Ubuntu linux" makes it sound like you are indeed running from the command line.  I think you should re-ask the question, and use a better title (at least mention JEE and the container you are using) and also tag the question with the web app you are using in addition to `java` and `rabbitmq`.  Right now I think the relevant folks are not looking at your question.  You also might try the RabbitMQ mailing list, which is referred to in a few places in the documentation.

Comment: I'll add: I'm absolutely not an expert, I'm reading the tutorials, but based on general knowledge you can't do what you are asking.  JEE runs over HTTP and HTML.  The protocol used by RabbitMQ, AMQP, appears to be different.  Unless it is a standard to run AMQP over HTTP (and the other side would have be running that exact same configuration) I don't think you can use a container here at all.  Emphasizing again that I'm not an expert.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, but I'm not looking how to run the consumer inside a web application. The producer is a web-application that fills the queue, but the consumer (it just sends email) is just a backend application. And this is exactly the point, how can I deploy a consumer application? I'm concerned about it crashes and nothing will revive it automatically. Maybe the consumer has to be wrapper in a OS service, I did not fond something useful about this in Rabbitmq docs.